# Google SSO redirect callback as a POST instead of a GET request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, single-sign-on, google-identity

Is there a way to have the redirection callback from Google SSO made as a POST request instead of a GET request, that way all the parameters would be encoded in the body.
Microsoft allows it by changing the response_body parameter when creating the flow.